# Android notification small icon zooms in in notification drawer

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, icons

So I am generating an Android notification and setting the small icon property to an image that is 400x400 pixels. The image looks as it's supposed to in the notification bar (see below - it's the yellow circle with green/red outline thing).

[image]

The problem is that when you pull down the notification drawer, the image for the notification's small icon is zoomed in and doesn't look as it should (see image 2). I want it to be that exact same image as the icon in the notification drawer, too.

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens / how to make the original image be the actual small icon?? Please let me know :( thanks.

Comment: 400x400 sounds big. Not that that is necessarily the issue, but it sounds big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the Guidelines :

> [Notification icons must be 24x24 dp](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification).

400x400 px sounds a very big size, i use in some applications the launcher icons, even the xxhdpi (144x144) and xxxhdpi (192x192) will load with no problem.

Comment: Ah gotcha I see. Thanks. Do you know what 24x24 dp translates to in pixels?

Comment: value in db multiplied by "multiplier" (:P) - ldpi m=0.75, mdpi m=1, hdpi m=1.5, xhdpi m=2, xxhdpi m=3, xxxhdpi m=4, so 24dp for xhdpi is 24x 2 = 48px etc.

Comment: @Jorgesys You're welcome. also you might edit your answer - 24 dp (not db, can't edit) in xxhdpi is 72 px, not 144. px values you wrote are for e.g. launcher icon (which is 48 dp always)